# Where can I see a list of reserved events in Socket.io

Tags: node.js

For example, in socket.io there is a reserved event 'disconnect'. Where can I find a list of full events?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the full list in the source code.
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.ts#L46